# iOS 7 UIActionSheet Transparent

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactionsheet

I am testing a few things within iOS 7 on both the simulator and real device. I have a few `UIActionSheets`, that used to have a `UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque` style. Since reading Apples guidance [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/TempViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH11-SW1)
I understand that you are no longer allowed to style a `UIActionSheet`.

Within iOS 7 all of my Action Sheets are showing up with completely transparent backgrounds and have none of the expected bordering / button outlines / etc.

Has anyone else experienced this and know how to get the default iOS 7 style?

For info, I am compiling my App with a base SDK of 6.1 - could this cause an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouches , I run into the same issue . Luckily , I have it resolved . set the background color and alpha

Comment: Mine turned out to be the alpha that was making it react in such a way. I chucked a quick check to see if the version is less than 7.0 and if so, I apply the alpha and actionSheetStyle, if not, I dont. - this seems to work on 7 and before as required. Cheers